# Can I use .com and .co.uk domain with wordpress multisite?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have two WordPress sites .com and .co.uk I wan't to expand and add a Spanish and French site. I have installed WordPress with multisite enabled and have set it up with the .com site. I wan't to add the .co.uk site but I don't want it to be .com/uk I wan't to use the .com and .co.uk and for the Spanish and French site it will be .com/es and .com/fr. So basically I wan't four sites on one WordPress multisite install using .com, .com/es, .com/fr and .co.uk is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe issues like this **are to be handled with Domain Mapping plugins**, for example you can try [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/), where all of the mapping will be done by Super Admin of course.

Also, as an addition you might want to take a look at this tutorial http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/

Hope this helps, all best!